# Merge javascript objects in an array based on an array inside it

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash, underscore.js

What is the best way to reorganize array into output? I need to merge all value keys (whether array or not) into objects sharing the same name key. There is something similar here, but that doesn't answer my question because I have arrays as well.

```
var array = [{
  VULN: [{random1:"asd11",random2:"asd12"}, {random3:"asd23",random4:"asd24"}]
}, {
  VULN: [{random5:"asd35",random6:"asd36"}, {random7:"asd47",random8:"asd43"}]
}, {
  VULN: [{random9:"asd55",random10:"asd51"}, {random11:"asd56",random12:"asd63"}]
}];
```

to

```
VULN=[{random1:"asd11",random2:"asd12"}, {random3:"asd23",random4:"asd24"},{name:"asd3",value:"asd3"}, {random5:"asd35",random6:"asd36"}, {random7:"asd47",random8:"asd43"}, {random9:"asd55",random10:"asd51"}, {random11:"asd56",random12:"asd63"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap):

```
array.flatMap(x => x.VULN);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you want:

```js
var array = [{
    VULN: [{ name: "asd1", value: "asd1" }, { name: "asd2", value: "asd2" }]
}, {
    VULN: [{ name: "asd3", value: "asd3" }, { name: "asd4", value: "asd4" }]
}, {
    VULN: [{ name: "asd5", value: "asd5" }, { name: "asd6", value: "asd6" }]
}];

console.log(array.map(x => x.VULN).flat())
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#flatten)

```
lodash.flatten(array.map(x => x.VULN))
```